# c++ less operator overload, which way to use?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

For example: in a C++ header file, if I defined a `struct Record` and I would like to use it for possible sorting so that I want to overload the `less operator`. Here are three ways I noticed in various code. I roughly noticed that: if I'm going to put `Record` into a `std::set`, `map`, `priority_queue`, … containers, the version 2 works (probably version 3 as well); if I'm going to save `Record` into a `vector<Record> v` and then call `make_heap(v.begin(), v.end())` etc.. then only version 1 works.

```
  struct Record
  {
      char c;
      int num;

      //version 1
      bool operator <(const Record& rhs)
      {
         return this->num>rhs.num;
      }

      //version 2
      friend bool operator <(const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) //friend claim has to be here
      {
         return lhs->num>rhs->num;
      }
  };
```

in the same header file for example:

```
      //version 3
      inline bool operator <(const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs)
      {
         return lhs->num>rhs->num;
      }
```

Basically, I would like to throw the questions here to see if someone could come up with some summary what's the differences among these three methods and what are  the right places for each version?

Comment: could you please post complete example programs for each case that Does Not Work

Comment: http://ideone.com/issBj  all scenarios work on this compiler

Comment: sorry, I didn't finish editing the question first. Now,it should be complete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are essentially the same, other than the first being non-const and allowing you to modify itself.

I prefer the second for 2 reasons:

1. It doesn't have to be a `friend`.
2. `lhs` does not have to be a `Record`

Comment: I think the 2nd version, if you claim the operator < inside the class definition, you have to claim it as a friend of the class

Comment: @user268451 It doesn't have to be a friend. It actually is best if it *isn't* one, as it leads to better encapsulation.

Comment: @Pubby8 If you want to define a free function from inside a class, you'll have to add `friend`. This has nothing to do with accessing the private members.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to define the less operator is:

```
struct Record{
    (...)
    const bool operator < ( const Record &r ) const{
        return ( num < r.num );
    }
};
```

Comment: This does not allow conversions on the left hand side, so definitely is not the *best way*.

Comment: The path of ipmlicit conversions is dangerous and thy shall not walk

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) where we have even more options.

```
  //version 1
  bool operator <(const Record& rhs)
  {
     return this->num>rhs.num;
  }
```

this one is wrong, it should read:

```
  //version 1
  bool operator <(const Record& rhs)const
  {
     return this->num>rhs.num;
  }
```

as you want the left hand side to be const-qualified as well.

```
  //version 2
  friend bool operator <(const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) //friend claim has to be here
  {
     return lhs->num>rhs->num;
  }
```

this one is symmetric.  So suppose you have a `struct Bar` with an `operator Record`.

Then

```
Record rhs;
Bar lhs;
assert( lhs < bar );
```

the above works with a symmetric case, but not with a member function version.

The `friend` in class version is an operator that can only be found via Koenig lookup (Argument Dependent Lookup).  This makes it very useful for when you want a symmetric operator (or one where the type is on the right, like `ostream&<<*this`) bound to a specific template class instance.

If it is outside of the class, it has to be template function, and a template function does overloading differently than a non-template function does; non-template functions permit conversion.

```
template<class T>
struct point {
  T x ,y;
  point operator-(point const& rhs)const{
    return {x-rhs.x,y-rhs.y};
  }
  friend point operator+(point const& lhs, point const& rhs) {
    return {lhs.x+rhs.x, lhs.y+rhs.y};
  }
};
template<class T>
point<T> operator*( point<T> const& lhs, point<T> const& rhs ) {
  return {lhs.x*rhs.x, lhs.y*rhs.y};
}
```

here `-` is asymmetric, so if we have a type that converts to a `point<int>` on the left, `-` won't be found.

`+` is symmetric and a "Koenig operator", so it is a non-template operator.

`*` is symmetric, but is a template operator.  If you have something that converts-to-point, it won't find the `*` overload, because deduction will fail.

```
  //version 3
  inline bool operator <(const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs)
  {
     return lhs->num>rhs->num;
  }
```

this is similar to the `template` above, but here that problem doesn't occur.  The difference here is that you can get the address of this function outside of the class, while the "koenig `operator<`" you wrote can only be found via ADL.  Oh, and this isn't a friend.

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) adds in

```
 auto operator<=>(const Record&)=default;
```

where we use the spaceship operator `<=>` to define ordering automatically.

This will use the ordering of both `c` and `num` to produce the required result.

Much like the rule of 5, you should seek to make `=default` here work correctly.  Having state that `<` ignores is a bad smell, and so is entangling different parts of your state.

Answer (score 1):

1. The non-member equivalent of your member function

```c
bool operator <(const Record& rhs);
```

is

```
bool operator <(Record& lhs, const Record& rhs);  // lhs is non-const
```

Now STL containers treat the items they store as `const` (at least as long as the comparison operator is concerned). So they call `const-const` variant of your operator. If they don't find it (in case you provided variant 1 only) - it is a compile error.

2. If you provide both `const-const` member and `const-const` non-member:

```
    struct Record
    {
      bool operator <(const Record& rhs) const;
    };
    
    bool operator <(Record& lhs, const Record& rhs);
```

it is yet another compiler error because such definition leads to an ambiguity:

> If two matches are found at the highest level where a match is found,
> the call is rejected as ambiguous. /Stroustrup, C++, section 12.3.1/

3. Finally, (as noted in the previous answers) there's no need in the `friend` modifier since by default all fields of the `struct` are public.

PS `make_heap` doesn't expect the compared items to be `const` because it is a more low-level beast and using it you're kind of co-authoring a new heap-based library so it is your responsibility to track const-ness of items.

PPS `set` treatment of items as `const` does not protect you from modifying the keys of the items after they are inserted into the container - it will result in a runtime error (segfault) if you try it.

Answer (score -2):

Favor in-class unless it cannot be in-class because first argument is the wrong type.

Comment: Actually one should always favour out-of-class, so that conversions on both left and right types apply (and not just the right one). If possible to make it a non-friend then even better yet, since it decouples the operator from the class implementing it just in terms of the public interface.

Comment: You don't want conversions on comparison operators unless you're some kind of number!

Comment: @Joshua that's not always true, if some container (map, sorted-set, ...) needs it you might implement it for "non-number" classes.

Comment: Really, convert one type of collection to another implicitly?